# How to mock react component and check if called with props

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, react-testing-library

In another project that uses jest 26 I could do the following:

```js
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';
jest.mock('./ChildComponent', () => jest.fn(() => 'ChildComponent'));

const { container, debug } = render(<ParentComponent />);
expect(ChildComponent).lastCalledWith({a, b, c});

debug() // returns `<body><div>ChildComponent</div></body>`
```

Now in my current project that runs jest 27 I can't mock ChildComponent like that, I need to remove jest.fn for it to work: `jest.mock('./ChildComponent', () => () => 'ChildComponent');`
*fine, I can live with that...*

But, now when I expect child to be called with abc it says: `Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function`

I can't find anything in the [changelog](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#2700) of jest 27, has anyone run into this issue? How can I mock a react component to return a string PLUS check if called with props??

Answer (score 4):

There are other ways to do (without `resetMocks`):

**Number One**

```js
// You can mock the component to render nothing, but can test the props received
jest.mock('./ChildComponent', () => jest.fn(() => null));
```

**Number Two**

```js
// You can mock the component to render a simple div with the props received
// This will show a <div> with props on debug()
jest.mock('./ChildComponent', () =>
  jest.fn(props => <div {...props} />),
);
```

And to test it:

```js
render(<ParentComponent />);

// You have to set a second arg with {} to test work and get the received props
expect(ChildComponent).toHaveBeenCalledWith({a, b, c}, {});
```

Comment: With `resetMocks: true` I get `mockConstructor(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing.`

Comment: But yes, if my issue was not a configuration issue, your answer is 100% correct for this question

Comment: So did it work for you?

Comment: setting `resetMocks: false` in `package.json` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

**::Answering my own question::**

My issue was because `react-scripts` had set `resetMocks` to true so the mock was being reset before the test.

I had tried to change it in `jest.config.js` but it was also not working.

Adding `resetMocks: false` to `package.json` solved the issue for me.